# Unable to make a bot do different action

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I did [this bot](https://github.com/antoinecomp/bookchatbot) with starter-pack-rasa-stack which is able to make two kind of actions through get methods : jokes and booking rooms. If I am able to make him tell me jokes I have issues at making him register a reservations. That is to say it is able to call for the `ActionJoke` class in `actions.py` but not for `ActionBookRoom` class.

Indeed, even if every story call for `action_room` when provided all details like one can see in this one:

```
## Generated Story 7889435598882720442
* greet
    - utter_greet
* book_room
    - utter_ask_room
* book_room{"name_room": "blue"}
    - slot{"name_room": "blue"}
    - utter_ask_day
* book_room{"day": "tomorrow"}
    - slot{"day": "tomorrow"}
    - utter_ask_hour_start
* book_room{"hour_start": "10h"}
    - slot{"hour_start": "10h"}
    - utter_ask_duration
* book_room{"duration": "30 min"}
    - slot{"duration": "30 min"}
    - action_room
* goodbye
    - utter_goodbye
    - export
```

Yet it goes straight to goodbye and I don't know how I can retrain the model or train it online to make him take into account this new action.

So how can I make the bot doing this new action?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the new stories to training stories file and retrain the model by running the train script again (e.g. make train-core)

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: please take a look at the docs on how to train rasa core models: https://rasa.com/docs/core/policies/#training